# Typescript: What's the difference between an optional field and a union with undefined?

Tags: typescript

I want to define an interface with optional fields.  I thought the following were synonymous.

`(A)`:

```
interface State {
  userDetails: undefined | string | DataStructure | Error;
}
```

`(B)`:

```
interface State {
  userDetails?: string | DataStructure | Error;
}
```

But when I go to initialise the state, `(A)` forces me to explicitly set the field as undefined, like so:

```
static readonly initialAppState: AppState = {
  userDetails: undefined
};
```

But with `(B)` I can just omit the field completely:

```
static readonly initialAppState: AppState = { };
```

If I try to omit the field when using definition `(A)` Typescript will complain saying:

```
Property 'userDetails' is missing in type
```

Why do I have to set the field explicitly when using definition `(A)`?
What's the difference between the two definitions that forces this different requirement when initialising?

Typesript version: 2.3.4

---

**Edit**: If you found this question and the answer below interesting or relevant, you may want to know that TypeScript is changing in v4.4 to add the [--exactOptionalPropertyTypes](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4-beta/#exact-optional-property-types) flag.  This new flag will now cause an error on some of the original code that prompted me to ask this question.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Even at runtime there is a difference between a key with an undefined value and a key that doesn't exist. That TypeScript allows differentiating is not surprising.

Try this:

```
Object.keys({a: undefined});
```

If leaving `a` out and setting it's value to be `undefined` were the same thing then we'd expect the above to return an empty array, but in fact it returns

```
[ 'a' ]
```