# Why doesn't typescript undefined type behave same as optional?

Tags: typescript

Imagine we have interface

```
interface Foo {
  bar: number | undefined;
}
```

If we try to create object of type Foo like

```
const foo: Foo = {};
```

It won't compile because property bar is missing. But we say that it can be undefined, which will work if we explicitly set it to undefined, but that's exactly same if we do not set it at all. Shouldn't it do exactly same as following?

```
interface Foo {
   bar?: number;
}
```

For me this is an issue, because if we consider more complex example, where we have interface with a field, which can be optional by generic type. So like, if generic type is not specified, then field should be undefined, if it is specified, then it should be only of that type. For example

```
interface Foo<T = undefined> {
    bar: T;
    title: string;
}

const foo1: Foo = {
    title: 'TITLE'
};

const foo2: Foo<number> = {
    title: 'title',
    bar: 12
};
```

foo1 will fail to compile because property is missing, but it anyway has to be undefined, and if we specify it explicitly it will work, but that's exactly same.
I ended up solving this problem with inheritance, where base class doesn't have any generic parameters and the child has it strictly specified. But I am just curious if anyone knows a specific reason why undefined type is handled this way. Because I couldn't find any information about it myself.

Comment: I know you are not looking for an alternative solution (you mentioned you solved it with inheritance), but you can solve it with conditional types as well : `type Foo<T = undefined> = {
    title: string;
} & (T extends undefined ? {} : { bar: T});` And keep the same name for the version with type paramteres and the version without. The why question I am not sure on.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46397280/typescript-whats-the-difference-between-an-optional-field-and-a-union-with-und

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript: What's the difference between an optional field and a union with undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46397280/typescript-whats-the-difference-between-an-optional-field-and-a-union-with-und)

Comment: Btw, it looks like this was changed sometime between when the question was asked and current versions of TS. The example included above compiles for me

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The two type signatures aren't entirely equivalent (although they're close enough that the difference may not be apparent at first glance)!

- `bar?: number` expresses that the object might not have a field called `bar`.
- `bar: number | undefined` expresses that the object will always have a field called `bar`, but the value of that field might be *set* to `undefined`.

This difference might matter in some cases, as some runtime behaviors are dependent on the difference between a field being present and a field being set to undefined - consider if you called `Object.keys` on the object:

```
Object.keys({ bar: undefined }) // returns ["bar"]
Object.keys({})                 // returns []
```

Answer (score 11):

The simple reason appears to be that nobody has implemented it yet. The way the current type checker is implemented it ended up requiring properties of type `undefined` to be required, but there is a [proposal](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12400) to change the behavior in a way that makes more sense, but nobody has gotten to it yet.

A  workaround that keeps the same name for the type and makes the field optional could be achieved using conditional types:

```
type Foo<T = undefined> = {
    title: string;
} & (T extends undefined ? {} : { bar: T});

const foo1: Foo = {
    title: 'TITLE'
};

const foo2: Foo<number> = {
    title: 'title',
    bar:10
};
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution that worked for was to use this utility type:

```
type KeysOfType<T, SelectedType> = {
  [key in keyof T]: SelectedType extends T[key] ? key : never;
}[keyof T];

type Optional<T> = Partial<Pick<T, KeysOfType<T, undefined>>>;

type Required<T> = Omit<T, KeysOfType<T, undefined>>;

export type OptionalUndefined<T> = Optional<T> & Required<T>;
```

Example

```
type MyType = {
    foo: string | undefined;
}

const willFail: MyType = {};

const willNotFail: OptionalUndefined<MyType> = {};
```

Taken from https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12400#issuecomment-758523767

Answer (score 1):

Typescript 4.6

```
type TNullProperties<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as null extends T[K] ? K : never]?: T[K];
};

type TNotNullProperties<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as null extends T[K] ? never : K]: T[K];
};
```

Theses two can be used together to make only the null properties of an object optional.

```
{ key1: string | null; key2: string }
```

becomes

```
{ key1?: string | null | undefined; key2: string }
```

Answer (score 0):

#### TypeScript modeling of optional properties

TypeScript models JavaScript run-time behavior when it comes to reading an optional property:

```
interface Foo {
  bar?: number;
}

type Bar = Foo['bar'];
```

The `Bar` type is `number | undefined`<sup>X</sup>. This makes sense since the `bar` property may be missing, and reading a missing property evaluates to `undefined`.

When it comes to setting an optional property, however, TypeScript doesn't model JavaScript run-time behavior properly  (at least, not by default):

```
const foo: Foo = {
  bar: undefined,
};
```

The code above type checks even though `undefined` is not explicitly stated as a constituent of `bar`'s type. Unfortunately, this doesn't work nicely with JavaScript's `in` operator:

```
"bar" in foo; // --> true
```

So, if we assign `undefined` to the `bar` property – which does not explicitly include `undefined` as part of its type – the property is not considered missing.

#### Enabling `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` for proper modeling of optional properties

The option `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` was introduced to address the issue exposed above. With `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` enabled, the following code generates a type error:

```
const foo: Foo = {
  bar: undefined,
};
```

Giving us a hint:

> Consider adding 'undefined' to the types of the target's properties.

Now, for `bar` to accept `undefined`, its type must explicitly include `undefined`:

```
interface Foo {
  bar?: number | undefined;
}
```

---

<sup>X</sup>Technically, it's only true provided `strictNullChecks` is enabled, which is enabled by default if `strict` is. Otherwise, `Bar` would be `number`, and JavaScript run-time behavior would not be modeled appropriately when reading optional properties.