# how can i get proper type infer when useing union type with optional property as React props type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, type-inference

I want ts to infer v type properly when `a` is optional in union type.

```
import React from 'react';
type A = { a?: false; s: (v: number) => void };
type B = { a: true; s: (v: string) => void };
type Props = A | B;

const Comp: React.FC<Props> = () => null;
const node = <Comp s={(v) => void 0} />; // Parameter 'v' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

When I change `A.a` to the required key, the inference is proper.

Answer (score 1):

You should explicitly define `a` property:

```js
import React from 'react';
type A = { a?: false; s: (v: number) => void };
type B = { a: true; s: (v: string) => void };

type Props = A | B;

const Comp: React.FC<Props> = () => null;

const node = <Comp a={undefined} s={(v) => void 0} />; // Parameter 'v' number
const node1 = <Comp a={false} s={(v) => void 0} />; // Parameter 'v' number
const node2 = <Comp a={true} s={(v) => void 0} />; // Parameter 'v' stirng
```

> But why does ts not treat the optional property as undefined?

```js
type A = {
    age: number | undefined
}

type B = {
    age?: number
}


let x: A = {
    age: 32
}

let y: B = {
    age: undefined
}

y = x // ok
x = y // error
```

This is because:

```js
const x = {
    age: undefined
}

const y = {}
```

`x` and `y` are completely different. They have different interfaces/shapes

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490773/why-doesnt-typescript-undefined-type-behave-same-as-optional) answer might help you to understand this better

Comment: Thanks! it works. But why does ts not treat the optional property as `undefined`?