# Short and clear syntax for setting property if a value is not undefined?

Tags: typescript

I want to set a property to a value only if the value is not undefined, otherwise I don't want to set the property.

This is how I usually handle this scenario:

```
  const payload: UpdateDistributionCommandInput = {
    Id: cloudFrontId,
    DistributionConfig: {
      ...distribution.DistributionConfig,
      Aliases: {
        Items: modifiedAliasItems,
        Quantity: modifiedAliasItems.length
      }
    }
  }

  if (typeof distribution.ETag === "string") {
    payload.IfMatch = distribution.ETag;
  }

  const updateDistributionCommand = new UpdateDistributionCommand(payload)
```

It looks a bit verbose and messy to me. Is there any shorter syntax for this, or other way of approaching this scenario?

Comment: This isn’t a typescript specific question, you might want to switch the tag to JavaScript to get more feedback.

Comment: Is the reason for asking because you are later using Object.keys() (or similar) and don’t want to deal with undefined?  Or just looking for a more succinct expression?

Comment: @DaveMeehan: When the code was JavaScript then I could assign 'string | undefined' to the 'IfMatch' property. But when I switched to TypeScript the compiler started complaining because of how the typings are setup, 'payload.IfMatch?: string'. So I need to not set the property at all when the value was undefined.

Comment: Do you have control over the types?  An optional property cannot be of type 'undefined' unless its explicit (e.g. `foo?: string | undefined`).  So if the type is optional but not a union with `undefined`, then yes, you must use an expression that avoids assigning undefined, null or any other type.  What you have seems unambiguous, I don't think you should use expressions like in the answer given because an assignment as a right hand side-effect to a logical expression is very muddy IMHO (I suspect linters would complain about such a construct).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dave, that's very helpful. I don't have any control of the types. The types are provided by '@aws-sdk/client-cloudfront'.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490773/why-doesnt-typescript-undefined-type-behave-same-as-optional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `payload.ifMatch` is defined as `ifMatch?: string` then the behaviour is dependent on the `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` compiler option.

Consider:

```
interface Payload {
  ifMatch?: string
}
```

**With `exactOptionalPropertyTypes: false`**, this will work:

```
const payload: Payload = {
  ifMatch: undefined
}
```

as will:

```
const payload: Payload = {}
payload.ifMatch = undefined
```

**With `exactOptionalPropertyTypes: true`**, you'll get errors:

```
const payload: Payload = {
  //  ^^^^^^^
  // Type '{ ifMatch: undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'Payload' with 'exactOptionalPropertyTypes: true'. Consider adding 'undefined' to the types of the target's properties.
  //  Types of property 'ifMatch' are incompatible.
  //    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2375)
  ifMatch: undefined
}

payload.ifMatch = undefined
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^
// Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string' with 'exactOptionalPropertyTypes: true'. Consider adding 'undefined' to the type of the target.(2412)
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?exactOptionalPropertyTypes=false#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQAUEE8A2B7BAE1QG9hULUQ4BZBCJACwH4AuVAZwhnAHNgAvsGBI8YLqgAO2fEXaZcBYgF5S5KrXpN2AVzCEoccFEKDh0xUQB01Og0apVeg0bAnhQA) (Toggle `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` in the TS Config menu)

Answer (score -1):

You could use the "and" operator.

```js
distribution.ETag && payload.IfMatch = distribution.ETag
```

You could also use the ternary operator.

```js
paylod.IfMatch = distribution.ETag 
  ? distribution.ETag
  : payload.IfMatch
```

The nullish coallescing operator (??) would also do.

```js
paylod.IfMatch = distribution.ETag ?? payload.IfMatch
```

In your example however, you check specifically for a "string" which is different than "not undefined". My solutions will assign as long as the value is not `null` or `undefined`. Also, my second and third solutions do in fact always "assign" `IfMatch` (`undefined` or a value). If you rely on the property not being assigned, for instance if you use `Object.keys()`, then this could be an issue.

Comment: The question specifically asked how not to set the property. Your 2nd and 3rd suggestions would always cause the property to be set to either a value or the value undefined.

Comment: Not exactly no, the `IfMatch` property would be set to its original value, effectively not changing it, if `ETag` is nullish, and it would be set to the value of `ETag` if it has a value. In other words, it will not set `IfMatch` to `undefined` unless `IfMatch` is already `undefined` in the first place.

Comment: But if its not defined (the property doesn't exist) when evaluated, then you would be setting it to `undefined`.  There is a difference between a missing property and a property set as undefined. [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQDED2nUG9iqGpzYD8AXKgM4QzgDmwAvsKJLIiqgEIIx4EiAIz4VqtBs2BJMYGsWyUsOALx4WMuRFQiYlXvzW4W02VUwAbKADoLmegAoSmAJStn156jW7ru1prmVrb2TthuQA)

Comment: Yes you are right. This could be a non-issue depending on the context since accessing `foo.foo` before or after the undefined assignment has the same behavior.

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify that.