# Why TypeScript can't recognize optional property when using union type instead of question mark?

Tags: typescript

Here is a minimum example:

```
type RGBA =
  | {
      r: number;
      g: number;
      b: number;
      a: number;
    }
  | {
      r: number;
      g: number;
      b: number;
    };

function process(rgba: RGBA) {
  const { r, g, b, a } = rgba;
}
```

Property A supposes to be optional, but TypeScript thinks it does not exist on the type.

Do I have to strictly specify optional property by using a question mark?

[image]

Comment: You'll have to discriminate inside the function which kind of RGBA you have, because not *all* members of the union have a.

Comment: not all members of the union have a === a is optional.   

Why this behavior is not equivalent to putting a question mark in the type

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46397844/3001761

Comment: Also, the type `{rgb: number}` (<--brevity) isn't known *not* to have an `a` key, since an object of type `{rgb: number; a: string}` is assignable to it (although [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks) complicates this).  So what you want is closer to `{rgb: number; a?: undefined}`.  But the union `{rgb: number; a: number} | {rgb: number; a?: undefined}` has very little going for it compared to just `{rgb: number; a?: number}`.  Is there a reason you want a union here?