# In TypeScript, is there a difference between optional parameters and parameters than can be undefined?

Tags: typescript

I was wondering if there was a difference between the these two bits of code:

```
function sayHello(name?: string) {
  if (name) { return 'Hello ' + name; }
  return 'Hello!';
}
```

and

```
function sayHello(name: string | undefined) {
  if (name) { return 'Hello ' + name; }
  return 'Hello!';
}
```

(I know that I couldn't put a second argument that isn't optional after the 'name' as it has to be the last or one of the last ones)

I was thinking about this earlier today, and I feel that the major difference for me first is what you're saying the consumer of the function.

The first is more implying optionality, like "you don't need to pass me this, but you can if you want"
The second says "pass me a string, I don't care if it's undefined, I can handle that".

A similar thing can come up in interfaces and types, too.

```
interface Foo {
   thing?: string;
}
```

vs

```
interface Foo {
   thing: string | undefined;
}
```

Am I on the right track here? Anything else I should know?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript: What's the difference between an optional field and a union with undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46397280/typescript-whats-the-difference-between-an-optional-field-and-a-union-with-und)

Comment: It does for objects (and objects that conform to interfaces) but perhaps not in the content of methods?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're on the right track and pretty much correct.

---

In what follows, I am going to assume you are using the `--strict` or at least the [`--strictNullChecks`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks) compiler option so that `undefined` and `null` are not always implicitly allowed:

```
let oops: string = undefined; // error! 
// Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

---

In TypeScript, a function/method parameter or object type's field that is marked as *optional* with the `?` modifier means that it can be *missing*:

```
function opt(x?: string) { }

interface Opt {
    x?: string;
}

const optObj: Opt = {}; // okay
opt(); // okay
```

but such optional parameters/fields are also allowed to be *present but `undefined`*:

```
const optObj2: Opt = { x: undefined } // okay
opt(undefined); // okay
```

In fact, if you use IntelliSense to examine the types of such optional parameters/fields, you'll see that the compiler automatically adds `undefined` as a possibility:

```
function opt(x?: string) { }
// function opt(x?: string | undefined): void

interface Opt {
    x?: string;
}
type AlsoOpt = Pick<Opt, "x">;
/* type AlsoOpt = {
    x?: string | undefined;
} */
```

From the point of view of the *implementer* of the function or the *consumer* of the object type, the optional element can be treated as if it is always present, but possibly `undefined`:

```
function opt(x?: string) {
    // (parameter) x: string | undefined
    console.log(typeof x !== "undefined" ? x.toUpperCase() : "undefined");
}

function takeOpt(v: Opt) {
    const x = v.x;
    // const x: string | undefined
    console.log(typeof x !== "undefined" ? x.toUpperCase() : "undefined");
}
```

---

Compare and contrast this with a required (non-optional) field or parameter that includes `| undefined`:

```
function req(x: string | undefined) { }

interface Req {
    x: string | undefined
}
```

Like optional versions, the required one with `| undefined` accepts an explicit `undefined`.  But unlike the optional versions, the required ones cannot be called or created with the value missing entirely:

```
req(); // error, Expected 1 arguments, but got 0!
req(undefined); // okay
const reqObj: Req = {}; // error, property x is missing!
const reqObj2: Req = { x: undefined } // okay
```

And, like with the optional versions, the implementer of the function or the consumer of the object type will see the optional things as definitely present but possibly `undefined`:

```
function req(x: string | undefined) {
    // (parameter) x: string | undefined
    console.log(typeof x !== "undefined" ? x.toUpperCase() : "undefined");
}

function takeReq(v: Req) {
    const x = v.x;
    // const x: string | undefined
    console.log(typeof x !== "undefined" ? x.toUpperCase() : "undefined");
}
```

---

**Other things to note:**

---

There are also [optional elements in tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#optional-elements-in-tuple-types) which work the same way.  They are like optional object fields but they have the same restriction as parameters: if any tuple element is optional, all subsequent ones also have to be optional:

```
type OptTuple = [string, number?];
const oT: OptTuple = ["a"]; // okay
const oT2: OptTuple = ["a", undefined]; // okay

type ReqTuple = [string, number | undefined];
const rT: ReqTuple = ["a"]; // error! Source has 1 element(s) but target requires 2
const rT2: ReqTuple = ["a", undefined]; // okay
```

---

For function parameters, you can also sometimes use the type `void` to mean "missing", and therefore `| void` to mean "optional", as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#27522](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/27522).  So `x?: string` and `x: string | void` are treated similarly:

```
function orVoid(x: string | void) {
    console.log((typeof x !== "undefined" ? x.toUpperCase() : "undefined"));
}
orVoid(); // okay
```

This is not yet the case for object fields.  It has been implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#40823](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40823), but has not yet made it into the language (and I'm not sure if it will ever do so):

```
interface OrVoid {
    x: string | void;
}
const o: OrVoid = {} // error! x is missing
```

---

Finally, I'll point you to [microsoft/TypeScript#13195](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13195), an issue discussing the funny historical relationship in TypeScript between "missing" and "present but `undefined`".  Sometimes they are treated identically, other times they are distinguished.

One major place where people would like more distinction is that when something is *optional*, developers are not always happy about the possibility of *explicitly passing in `undefined`*.  That is, people would like to say that `interface Opt {x?: string}` should mean that `x` is either a `string`, or it is missing entirely.  They think that if you have a value `o` of type `Obj`, then `o.x === undefined` should only happen when `"x" in o` is `false`.

But that's not what happens by default in TypeScript.  In most compilr configurations, `o.x === undefined` does not let you know whether or not the property is present-but-`undefined` or missing.  And so `"x" in o` doesn't conclusively tell you whether `o.x` is a `string` or `undefined`.

There is a new [`--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` compiler flag](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4-beta/#exact-optional-property-types) slated to be released with TypeScript 4.4 which, when enabled, will not add `undefined` to the domain of optional properties, and so `o.x === undefined` implies that the `x` property is missing.  This compiler option will not be enabled by default, though, and it only applies to properties and not function parameters.

In any case, I'd suggest avoiding situations where the difference between missing and `undefined` matters.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-y8PCIsF0hAA2h6cKasEQUlpWP4ALrbIOQKA8Iud7tCPs9JQ9KfVjNJmfQHiFiDIxc9iC91c9U0Njdx2tWOx3+wWaGuWFoEAARz8l1yNzWJQxTPJBIklSdI0EyL9PR-OUaCZINWXZRo21afFeRlBtBTGSZplYCUpQgFZ0K2XYrA+L4fiEAAld8gSxakBy9X9BmIixXw-LZq1Ydg0FNABRXxBBcCsAEYICSHARxALAwHgU0tCISAcEUCAAAZOBY99vAbdjr0zHdWLzZAqLfAkIhjDi2A4U1YHYGZmnxWQIBSWQ1FwNS9PfPN9yMkzS3pAYKyrHSk0fZxnw8MAERAIzvFRCAjP-LEdw6QgiRJADmCSiDrj8u5YMqeD6kQrkUO6NDGI2EZMNFbC5gWJZ8LK6ChiIvYlSMOL3yPZcTwHIcRzHNAGKaqcLD0+cOrfLqCVPNcr2YTiOG4ABlKAiDQX4IAACxUCARJAUA0ik7x4HCOTIAitAcHACBWKIDBXzkfNRuzNA90Mzqu2PGbzxyko5ubYL7wDBxQpOaA0AANReUhPxpb9CWhhLyny2pCu8TlBGQnlStlfyhkq4UsPFOrpVxu5Nha5NIeh1NNxvEipLIja-mp14aLdLK6WeV5FR3KA0VZ0gTMC+aLK4ey5Cc1QQiAA)

Comment: You may want to update your answer: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/43947

Comment: The answer already has a section that starts "There is a new --exactOptionalPropertyTypes compiler flag..."; did you mean something else?

Comment: Easy to miss in such a long answer, especially after it sneaks in past a "finally" that wasn't about this 