# how can I pass a useState props using TypeScript to a child component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

being new to Typescript in react application, I am trying to describe a JavaScript object using TypeScript. This object will be utilized in a useState hook, and then passed on to a child component.

I have created my interface like so :

```js
export interface IformEntry {
  type:string;
  toFrom:string;
  details:string;
  amount:number
}
```

Then here is my Home component which contains the state ( I simplified the code to get to the point )

```js
import FormulaireFooter from "../components/FormulaireFooter";
import { IformEntry } from "../interfaces/IformEntry";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Home() {

 const [formEntry, setformEntry] = useState<IformEntry | undefined>(undefined);
 
  return (
    <>
      <FormulaireFooter
        setformEntry={setformEntry}
        formEntry={formEntry}
      />
    </>
  )
}
```

and here is the formulaireFooter.tsx file, which is the child component I am passing the state to :

```js
import { IformEntry } from "../interfaces/IformEntry";

const FormulaireFooter = ({
  setformEntry,
  formEntry,
}
:{
  setFormEntry: any;
  formEntry: IformEntry;
  setFormList: any;
  formList: any;
}
) => { 
// TODO
}
```

so, what I am not fully understanding, is how I should redefine my useState hook in my child component?

because in the child component I get that message when I hover over my setFormEntry property:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared the `useState` saying it can either be `IFormEntry` **or** `undefined`. In the props of the child component, you have only said it can be `IFormEntry`. These don't match, which is why typescript is complaining.

You'll need to make the two types agree somehow.

One option would be to change the props definition to allow `undefined` as well.

```js
const FormulaireFooter = ({
  setformEntry,
  formEntry,
}
:{
  setFormEntry: any;
  formEntry: IformEntry | undefined; // <-- allow the same types here
  setFormList: any;
  formList: any;
}
) => { 
// TODO
}
```

Another option, which is the one I would suggest, is to make better default value for your state.

```js
const defaultState: IFormEntry = {
  type: '';
  toFrom: '';
  details: '';
  amount: 0
}

const [formEntry, setformEntry] = useState<IformEntry>(defaultState);
```

Comment: oh thanks so much, this is so obvious now that you put the finger on it ! that solved my problem !

Answer (score 2):

Your child component expects `IformEntry` but the React use state is initialised with undefined. We can either check if `IformEntry` is not undefined by doing a truthy check before rendering the child component.

```
export default function Home() {
  const [formEntry, setformEntry] = useState<IformEntry | undefined>(undefined);

  return (
    <>
      {formEntry && (
        <FormulaireFooter setformEntry={setformEntry} formEntry={formEntry} />
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Or alternative you can adjust the prop types for your child component to expect either `IformEntry` or `undefined`.

```
const FormulaireFooter = ({
  setformEntry,
  formEntry,
}: {
  setFormEntry: any;
  formEntry?: IformEntry;
  setFormList: any;
  formList: any;
}) => {
  // TODO
};
```

Comment: The `?` means the parameter is optional, not that it can be undefined. They're similar, but not the same. In other words, the prop could still be present, but hold the value of `undefined`. Unless I'm mistaken, it would still complain with the same error. ([for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46397280/typescript-whats-the-difference-between-an-optional-field-and-a-union-with-und))

Comment: @BrianThompson Interesting reply, although it does mark it as optional, the compiler will also add `undefined` to the parameter type, so you don't need to use `undefined` so verbosely. See `https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-johnson-36k42?file=/src/App.tsx` as an example, however I do agree that you should initialise the state with the default state.

Comment: Looks like you are correct. I could have sworn I've ran into that before and seen the opposite behavior, but I've tested it out on two different playgrounds and it does work that way, you're right.