# Typescript ? vs undefined

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, is there any difference between the following?

```
private dog: TDog | undefined;
```

vs

```
private dog?: TDog;
```

Also, what is the `?` called?

Comment: There's a lot of docs about it. https://kate-dev.medium.com/when-to-use-typescript-optional-property-how-is-it-different-from-declaring-property-as-undefined-2319a0ee1f07

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript: What's the difference between an optional field and a union with undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46397280/typescript-whats-the-difference-between-an-optional-field-and-a-union-with-und)

Answer (score 1):

`?` operator means that parameter is optional, it’s not necessary to pass it in component/function.

`undefined` means that parameter must be passed in but its value may be undefined.

A simple example:

```js
type A = {
    a?: string
}
type B = {
    a: string | undefined
}

const a: A = { }
const b: B = { }
```

Paste it into VSCode and you can see:

[image]

I once read [an article about this](https://kate-dev.medium.com/when-to-use-typescript-optional-property-how-is-it-different-from-declaring-property-as-undefined-2319a0ee1f07). Hope it helps you.